# How would I figure out which friends of a user is also using my app?

Tags: android, google-plus

I´m building a webapp+android app and thought it would be useful if I could show "Alice" which of her friends that also use the service.

User authentication is done through google oath2 so I have access to the email of all users.

What I´m wondering is how I would structure such a query? Since what I basically have is

- Users possibly huge list of people Alice:(bob@gmail.com, user..)
- The users in my database  (alice@gmail.com, bob@gmail.com, ..)
- Whether the "friendship" is reciprocal or not Bob:(alice@gmail.com, chet..) || (Chet@gmail.com, Diana..)

I would prefer not to have a "are we friends yes/no" system and looping through a users entire contactlist seems very wasteful. The backend runs on php+mysql.

How would I actually query for the list of people I´m interested in?

Comment: I assume that you have a backend where you're storing this information. What language is your backend using and what kind of datastore?

Answer (score 3):

[PhotoHunt](http://developers.google.com/+/photohunt) does this currently. It does this by performing the following steps:

1. Store user's Google+ id (or email, in your case) when they sign-in. For simplicity, let's call the first signed in user Alice.
2. When a new user, Bob, signs in, perform a [people.list](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/list) API call to list the Google+ IDs of people who Bob has made visible to your app and compare this against the Google+ ids already stored on your site for users.
3. If somebody in Bob's visible people is already on the site, as indicated by the comparison of Google+ ids, create an edge on your private social graph indicating that Bob has this relationship with Alice. For example, if Bob circled Alice on Google+, he has this relationship with Alice (Bob -> Alice, Bob circled Alice so the edge is Bob to Alice) and also create the connection from Alice to Bob (Alice has the relationship with Bob in that Bob has Alice in his circle).
4. The same relationship would be graphed for a third user, Chet, who both has Alice and Bob in visible circles and is in Bob and Alice's list of circles.

Visually, the graph I described is as follows, the arrows indicate an edge from one user to another:

[image]

For Photohunt, an edge from any user to any other user will create a relationship where they see each other as connected on the site. In doing this, you would create the most comprehensive graph of users, maximizing the connections between users and maximizing the amount of content that appears in the relational content stream.

As the graph is interpreted in this way for Photohunt, Bob, Alice, and Chet all see that they have a relationship through Google+ and this is reflected in the "social" stream of content. Computationally, you would only need to perform the check every time a new user connects with your site.

However, there could be privacy implications: Does Alice want Bob to know that she's on the site?

To mitigate this privacy concern, you can also perform another check when you recognize that Alice is in Bob's circles by then performing a second people.list API call on Alice's visible people. When there is a connection from Bob to Alice, you could make sure that Bob has a relationship to Alice before you expose that both users are on the site. As such, only those with mutual connections would be made aware that they are on the site. For this case, only Chet and Alice would see each other, and only Bob and Chet would see each other. Because Bob and Alice don't have a mutual connection, they don't see each other.

A third interpretation of the graph would be to keep track of the "is in visible people", relationships, keep track of the "is in my list of visible people", and finally, "has been made mutually visible" on your site.

As Brett indicated, and Joanna clarified, there are performance implications to generating the mutual relationships or partial relationships. You would either have to keep a graph of edges to Google+ user ids storing connections that don't yet exist on your site or you would have to effectively poll all users who a connection is recognized on. However, you could do this today if you wanted to invest the resources in generating a private graph. The implications for performing these computations on a phone are rather terrifying. If you were to do this, I would suggest calculating and maintaining the graph server-side on your PHP/MySQL server.

From a database perspective, you would only store the "edge" relationships. This greatly simplifies queries against the graph and only returns those users who have the correct edge constraints that you need for creating the relationships you want to track or expose.

Comment: The answer is very good and is most likely what I will end up doing. Although not what I was hoping for it will help me implement what is needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a known feature request for an API call that can do this.  If you'd like to track this progress of this API call, you can star the following issues to get email updates on it.
https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=531

Comment: I don't think this falls into the feature request category. You can do this today and many apps accomplish this already. I think he's right in the real question is how to do it efficiently.

Comment: Edited my answer for clarity--the most efficient way would be through an API call, and that is what the feature request is for.

Comment: I have starred the issue since it was basically what I was looking for. With some luck they'll release before I do.